# FlatList auto update or re-render react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am new to `react native` and I am stuck on this issue for 2 days now.
I am trying to add a new item to my list which is given to `Flatlist` as a state. I read that `FlatList` is a pure component and it doesn't re-render itself unless it is told via "extraData" and also when the value of state is changed the component re-renders itself but these two options don't seem to work for me. Clearly, I am doing something wrong or my concepts are not clear.
Have a look at my code.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, SafeAreaView, ToastAndroid } from 'react-native';



export default function App() {

  var dishList = [
    {
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      title: 'First Item',
    },
    {
      id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
      title: 'Second Item',
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
      title: 'Third Item',
    },
  ]
  const [dishes, setDishes] = useState(dishList)
  var count = 0;

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("use")
  },[dishes])

  const CustomDish = (props) => {
    return(
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <TouchableOpacity  >
          <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title} = {props.id}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <CustomDish title={item.title} id={item.id} />
  );

  function addItem(){
    count = count + 1;
    console.log("Count: "+ count)
    var i = {
      id: `${count}`,
      title: `${count + " Item"}`,
    }
    dishList.push(i)
    setDishes(dishList)
    console.log("state length: "+ dishes.length)
    console.log("list length: "+ dishList.length)
    
  }

  function renderScreen(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', flex:1,width:'100%', height:"100%"}}>
        <SafeAreaView style={{margin: 20}} >
          <FlatList
            data={dishes}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          />
      </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={addItem} >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText} >Add</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText} >Remove</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
    )
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      {renderScreen()}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  button:{alignSelf: 'auto',backgroundColor: 'red', height: 50, width: 100, justifyContent:"center", margin: 10},
  buttonText:{alignSelf: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold'},
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },

});
```

What I am trying to do here is to press the "Add" button and add a new item to my list and also show a view to represent that it is added to the list. so in console.log the value of my list and state does update, its length does change from 3 to 4 and 4 to 5 and so on each time I press the button but on the screen, the FlatList doesn't render any new components, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this

```
function addItem() {
    count = count + 1;
    console.log("Count: " + count);
    var i = {
        id: `${count}`,
        title: `${count + " Item"}`,
    }
    let dishTemp = [...dishes];
    dishTemp.push(i);
    setDishes(dishTemp);
    console.log("state length: " + dishes.length);
    console.log("list length: " + dishList.length);
}
```

Comment: Oh my god bro, Wow. Thank You so mush...! it worked. I don't have enough reputation but mark this comment as a Upvote from me.
Also can you tell me what is the difference in my approach and your approach and what does[...] three dots means?

Comment: You were pushing the new Item in static array which do not rerender the dishes state every time you try to push something new into it, In this approach now you are spreading the state into a local variable dishTemp so everything in the state comes into dishTemp and after that you push a new item and update the state so it will now rerender, it won't work if you do let dishTemp = dishes, instead of let dishTemp = [...dishes]

Answer (score 0):

The **count variable will reset at every re-render** cycle.

You should **move the count variable declaration to outside** the App component.

Like:

```
var count = 0;

export default function App() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes I noticed and have fixed it by making the count also a state. Thank you for the feedback.